# Add a conf menu to my portlet

Tags: liferay, portlet

I'm trying to add a tab in the conf of my custom portlet, beside the natives import/export and permissions.

Like in this image : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/716/sampledn.png/

This tab had to allow, to change the value of a parameter in a conf.properties which define some variable.

How can I do that?

Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup you can do it by first of all adding this to your portlet.xml as a child of the "portlet" node:

```
    <init-param>
        <name>config-jsp</name>
        <value>/html/config.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
```

The in your liferay-portlet.xml you need to add this as a child of the "portlet" node:

```
<configuration-action-class>com.yourportlet.action.ConfigurationActionImpl</configuration-action-class>
```

Then you need to create this files in the directories you've specified in your XML, and your ConfigurationActionImpl should implement the ConfigurationAction interface so the skeleton would look like this:

```
public class ConfigurationActionImpl implements ConfigurationAction {

@Override
public String render(PortletConfig config, RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {                   
    return "/html/config.jsp";
}
```

Let me know if this helps or you have any other questions! :)

Comment: This help a little yea, but i have other questions with : If i implements ConfigurationAction in my portlet class, instead create a new class, is <configuration-action-class>com.yourportlet.action.ConfigurationActionImpl</configuration-action-class> became <configuration-action-class>com.yourportlet.action.myportletclass</configuration-action-class> ?
ps : i can't vote up because of my reputation(less 15),but thanks

Comment: You don't want your portlet to implement ConfigurationAction (in truth I don't know if this would work or not) as you want to keep this logic separate from your Portlet code if that makes sense. You're best off creating separate classes for Configuration and Portlet.

Comment: If it works, then just accept the answer and don't worry about voting up! :) If you have any more questions just ask!

Comment: When i add the line ine the liferay-portlet.xml, i have this error : "This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page." I check the name, and there is no error. How is that possible?

Comment: This usually happens when a portlet has tried to be redeployed but there is an error, so it's been removed from the server and not fully deployed again. Do you get any errors in your Log when deploying? Have you tried re-deploying your portlet?

Comment: Ok, i found the error. I don't create a folder action for the class ConfigurationActionImpl, and put it in the same folder as my portlet. Can i stay in this configuration or sould i create "action" folder?
Now i can continue.
There is a way for me, to modify a variable into a myportlet-conf.properties?

Comment: No you can keep it in the same folder, but it's advised to separate it out as good coding practice. If you have got it in a different folder make sure you change the classpath in your liferay-portlet.xml. Sorry I don't quite get your second question. Might be best to start a new question rather than asking another in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Add edit mode to your portlet.xml:

```
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
        <portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
        <portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode> <!-- add this line -->
    </supports>
```

Then you will see preferences option in the menu. Override doEdit method in your portlet class to render content of the edit mode.

**EDIT:**

More advanced solution:

You can add another tab by changing portal jsp via hook. The jsp you need to change is:

/html/portlet/portlet_configuration/tabs1.jsp

Note that this will change configuration window for ALL portlets.

Comment: I have really do this with a preferences menu? I think i can make like in the image i link(edit my questions with it).